# Write `.htaccess` regex to redirect URL to previous category/sub-directories

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have a site at **www.test.com**. The site has many nested directories and categories such as **www.test.com/cat/1/321/**.

I want to use a Regex to remove any url ending in **`/321/`** or **`/321`** to the previous category.

**Example**: Redirect `www.test.com/cat/1/321/`  to  `www.test.com/cat/1/`

Needed for a Wordpress site using `.htaccess`. Thanks!

Comment: What have you done so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can write your conditions and rules for exam in this code we have to conditions for /321/ and /321

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /321/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/321/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /321$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/321$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*/)321/?$ $1 [R,L]
```